# replacing new line with br error

Tags: php

I'm using a comment box to submit comments. Users when entered any comment and press enter for a new line then after submit I used to update it to database using `$update=mysql_real_escape_string($update);` for security purpose.

But when that comment is shown the new line was replaced by alphabet 'n' and the whole sentence which should come like this

```
John is awesome
He loves food
```

comes like:

```
John is awesome nHe loves food
```

I searched the error in stack and found a solution:

I replaced `<?php echo $message; ?>` with `<?php echo str_replace('\n',"<br/>", $message); ?>` which did the job. but when I tried commenting `'n'` it comes out to be `\'n\'` any solution for that?

Comment: Don't forget to use `htmlspecialchars()` when _outputting_ from a database for security purposes as well.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion , i really forgot that one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated:

```
$output = htmlspecialchars($message);
$output = str_replace('\\n','<br/>', $output);
$output = stripslashes($output);
echo $output;
```

[stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) should take care of the `\'n\'` problem as well as many others.

Note that the order of these commands matters. If you strip slashes first, you’ll mess up the **str_replace**. If you use **htmlspecialchars** after **str_replace**, it will mess up your `<br/>`.

Comment: this works but is still does not solve my actual problem and that is if i input 'n' is being replaced by \'n\'

Comment: Sorry. I overlooked that part of the question. I updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: if i use strip slashes and if a user has posted a youtube video would it be effected as the link as slash?

Comment: Come to think of it, you shouldn't need to strip slashes. My guess is that you have magic quotes turned on. That should be turned off and you should be able to use _nl2br_ as everyone else has suggested.

Comment: emm..so if that magic quotes is off then ill be able to use the escape with the nl2br?

Comment: I've been looking into this since you posed the question and everything I've read so far seems to indicate that is the case. `magic_quotes` is a deprecated means for sanitizing user input. Most of us have it turned off so it's easy to overlook that as being part of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

[`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) will do the trick. It's a built-in function that will add newlines using the `<br>` tag.

```
echo nl2br($message);
```

Comment: Actually, it won’t replace them.

Comment: let me try this was something i didnt found

Comment: its not replacing them it comming like this now `i am\njohn`

Comment: You likely need to un-escape `$message`.

Comment: but that would cause security issues . scripts and all , any other solution?

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` protects your _database_ from malicious data going in. `htmlspecialchars()` protectes your _visitors_ from malicious data going out.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the native `nl2br()` function ?

```
$foo = nl2br("I love\n yo");
```

yields `I love<br /> you`.

Answer (score 0):

try to use  `<?php $var = preg_replace("[\n]","<br/>",$comment); ?>`

Example :

```
<?php
$text = "John is awesome
He loves food";
$echo = preg_replace("[\n]","<br/>",$text);
echo $echo;

?>
```

Comment: This just replaces the letter "n" with a line break. Does not work.